# Stuck finding product of data type IntList in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm brand spanking new to Haskell and functional programming in general so I'm having a little trouble iterating through a list to get the product.

IntList is defined as:

```
data IntList = Nil | Cons Integer IntList deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

My head immediately goes to some sort of recursion but I don't know how to move to the next element. Right now all I have is:

```
prod :: IntList -> Integer 
prod x = 
if(x == Nil)
    then 1
else x (Pretty sure x makes no sense here) * prod (No idea what to put here)
```

Does anybody have any guidance?

Comment: are you familiar with "pattern matching" in Haskell? If not, I suggest you look up a few simple examples of how it works, as that's exactly what you need here.

Comment: I keep seeing pattern matching, but I've been struggling to figure it out. In the meantime, I will keep throwing my head at it. I should be able to crack it eventually.

Comment: Your lists are either of the form `Nil` or of the form `Cons x xs` for some `x` and `xs`. It therefore suffices to define `prod Nil = ...` and `prod (Cons x xs) = ...`

Comment: If you've not seen it before, the book "Learn You a Haskell", which is available to read freely on the web, is by far the best Haskell beginner's resource (at least in my opinion, but I know that of many others too). [This section on recursive datatypes](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#recursive-data-structures) is probably the most relevant one for your usecase.

Comment: Not sure how digging through the internet for 30 minutes didn't give me that. Thank you very much, I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to consume data is via pattern matching.

```
prod x = case x of
    Nil -> {- you fill in here -}
    Cons n y -> {- you fill in here -}
```

In fact, this idiom of accepting an argument and immediately pattern matching on it is such a common way of defining functions that there is special syntax for it. The following is equivalent, except that the name `x` does not exist in the body of the function:

```
prod Nil = {- you fill in here -}
prod (Cons n y) = {- you fill in here -}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `x` is an `IntList`. We say `x` is of *type* `IntList` (written as `x :: IntList`) to distinguish it from variables of other types (say `Int` or `String`). Since you have `x :: IntList` you check the *data declaration*

```
data IntList = Nil | Cons Integer IntList deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

and conclude that `x` is either a `Nil` or a `Cons` (we call `Nil` and `Cons` *data constructors*). Distinguishing between the two is done using *pattern matching* and [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73887848/1671066) explains it in more detail. The difference between `Nil` and `Cons` is that the later has two *parameters*: a value of type `Integer` and a value of type `IntList`. Part of pattern matching is, that you give those values names (what we call *bind* a value to a name). In the case of `Cons n y` those values have been bound to `n` and `y`.

There might be another confusing thing going on. Looking again at your `IntList`, those are some example values:

```
empty_list = Nil
l1 = Cons 1 Nil
l2 = Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil)
l3 = Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3))
```

So you see this way of thinking about a list is probably different from what you have seen before. If you take a look at `l3` you might notice that you can access the 1 (the *head*) of the list more easily than values deeper down in the tail:

```
case l3 of
  Cons head tail -> head   -- here head == 1
```

To sum up you have to deal with three concepts:

- Pattern matching to distinguish the different constructors and binding their parameter values to names,
- a strange/new way of looking at lists,
- your actual problem of multiplying the items of a list.

So there is no doubt that this seemingly innocent exercise can be quite a bit overwhelming.